# How to size coupling and bypass capacitor for simple BJT CE stage

Tags: capacitor, bjt, coupling, bypass

I'm a new user in this forum and I want ask you a question about a simple CE BJT stage design.
I want to know,if possible, a procedure design for sizing coupling and bypass capacitor for following circuit
[image]

After sized R1,R2,Rc,Re for gain specifics and bias ,how to size C1,C2 and C3 for a low cut frequency?What is analytic procedure or way of thinking for sizing them?Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Without C2 the gain of the amplifier is approximately Rc/Re and, because you are adding C2 its low impedance shunts Re making the gain higher and sometimes considerably higher. At low frequencies that gain falls as the impedance of C2 rises and,

at f = \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi R_E C_2}\$ the gain has back to near enough the dc gain of the circuit.

C3 limits low frequencies being developed across RL and from midband, as the frequency drops, the 3dB point is f = \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi R_L C_3}\$.

Similar story for C1 - as the frequency lowers the AC voltage at the base will drop and the 3 dB point will be approximately when f = \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi R_1||R_2 C_1}\$.

Comment: The problem is the distribution of poles and zeros in bode diagram.There are 3 poles and 3 zeros,C1 and C3 introduces 2 zeros in origin and C2 a finite zero,C1 and C2 interact each other .How to size capacitors to set inf frequency cut?

Comment: I would not overcomplicate the task. Sizing of the capacitors (and the corresponding time constants resp. corner frequencies) depends on the desired operating frequencies. All capacitors should not influence the implemented gain more than 1% or less.